# .htaccess если есть cookie то запрет на папку

Tags: .htaccess, cookie, веб-программирование

есть директория - *public_html*

в ней находится - *.htaccess*

в директории public_html есть свои папки, как определить файлом *.htaccess* есть ли значение куки, если есть то запретить в нее доступ.

К примеру:

- есть папка - ***test***
- есть значение куки ***test=true***
- нужно запретить доступ к папке ***test***

можно ли такое сделать? если да, то подскажите как :-)

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю как-то так :)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*test=true.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule 403 /notfound.html
```